# Gadget OAuth2 from OpenID Authentication

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-openid, google-apps-marketplace

I am updating my app to OAuth2 and have few questions.

Email address is the user id in our application.

- As explained in the old docs for openid association with the user id in our app, we were showing a popup storing the open_social_id in the database and creating a temp session key. After the user was successfully associated, we were adding the open_social_id next to the user id looking at the temp session key. This was/is working fine. 
  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/best_practices#gadget_sso

But with oauth2, since we get the email address (From Contacts Scope of the current user who is logged in), I am trying to figure out how to authenticate this at my server? Should I accompany email address with open_social_id and rely on open_social_id everytime in the future? Is this the right way?

Or should I add OAuth2 proxy at my server to allow access with the right scope.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change too much.

In the old setup, you displayed a popup that passed through openId to get the user's identity and e-mail address.

In the new setup, you show a popup that does an OAUTH2 dance to get the user's identity and e-mail address.

Because the scopes are pre-authorized, the end user will not see the consent screen and from a end user's perspective, nothing really changes.

Comment: Does it mean the following? Signing a request which sends the open_social_id. Storing it in the backend and creating a session_key. User consents via a popup (session_key as param) using OAuth2. User is mapped with open_social_id based on the session_key once the authentication is complete. User then sends open_social_id and the server looks up.

Comment: Different related question. After the OAuth2 dance, is there a way to send the params back to the gadget automatically? This will eliminate the relating session_key with open_social_id. User will do oauth authentication and we store the email address automatically. window.parent didn't work as it is cross-domain. Any ideas or is open_social_id+Session+popup+Associating-open_social-with-contact the right way?

Comment: Open the popup and pass the open_social_id. After auth, you have both the open_social_id and the email address in the popup and you send both to the server. store this correlation. from then on, any request from the gadget with opensocialid can be linked back to the emailaddress. No need to compliciate things with a session keys.

Comment: How do I pass the open_social_id as it is known only while signing? Should the server send it's open_Social_id back in the response. Thanks.

Comment: when the gadget starts, do a io.makeRequest call to the server to see if you know the identity. if you do, all is fine. if you don't, return the open_social_id and start the popup.